# ASP.Net MS Chart: Image Missing

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, mschart

I'm trying to get my first MS Chart to appear - just a simple line. However, when I click debug (VS2010), all I get is a missing image icon on the webpage (regardless of browser). The chart has been copied from the MS Chart Samples.

My first thought was that MS Chart hadn't installed correctly, but all the samples work great when debugging the Samples Environment. It's just my own test page that fails to render the image.

Where am I going wrong???

Here's the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages theme="xxx">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

</configuration>
```

Here's the page code:

```
<asp:chart id="chart1" runat="server" imagetype="Png" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" BorderWidth="2" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="White" Palette="BrightPastel" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderColor="26, 59, 105" Height="296px" Width="412px">
     <titles>
          <asp:title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0" Font="Trebuchet MS, 12pt, style=Bold"  ShadowOffset="3" Text="Two series with 20000 points each." ForeColor="26, 59, 105">
          </asp:title>
    </titles>
    <legends>
         <asp:legend Enabled="False" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default"  BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"></asp:legend>
    </legends>
    <borderskin skinstyle="Emboss"></borderskin>
    <series>
         <asp:series Name="Series1" ChartType="FastLine" ShadowColor="Black" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105"></asp:series>
         <asp:series Name="Series2" ChartType="FastLine" ShadowColor="Black" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="224, 64, 10"></asp:series>
    </series>
    <chartareas>
         <asp:chartarea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="Gainsboro" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
             <area3dstyle Rotation="10" perspective="10" Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False" wallwidth="0" IsClustered="False"></area3dstyle>
             <axisy linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                  <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                  <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
             </axisy>
             <axisx linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                  <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                  <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
             </axisx>
        </asp:chartarea>
    </chartareas>
</asp:chart>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Drawing;

public partial class reporting : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double yValue = 50.0;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 20000; pointIndex++)
        {
            yValue = yValue + (random.NextDouble() * 10.0 - 5.0);
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(yValue);
        }

        chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
    }
}
```

Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I worked with MS Chart, I had to supply a physical path for the images in the web config.  Otherwise I would only get a broken image.  None of the other options worked consistently but creating a c:\tempimages folder and setting this value did

Also, make sure that the IIS user for that machine has permissions to write to the folder.  Grant the permissions through IIS rather than windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a folder, and also give permissions to the IIS User to access that folder. The user that need access varies depending on Windows and IIS versions, so you would have to check it.